# Not loading 'libphp5' module with CA on apache2.4.51

Tags: php, macos, apache2.4

On Macbook M1Max. 
Installed PHP5.6 by 'shivammathur/php/php@5.6' via Homebrew.
And set the module info on a configuration file(httpd.conf) of Apache.

```
LoadModule php5_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so "apache2"
```

then passed apachectl syntax check that has no error.

```
$ apachectl configtest
[Fri Jan 14 19:48:05.352957 2022] [so:notice] [pid 5436] AH06662: Allowing module loading process to continue for module at /opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so because module signature matches authority "apache2" specified in LoadModule directive
Syntax OK
```

BUT, apache still occurred below errors.

```
[Fri Jan 14 19:50:25.774217 2022] [so:error] [pid 5534] /usr/bin/codesign failed; unable to obtain code signature for module
[Fri Jan 14 19:50:25.774243 2022] [so:error] [pid 5534] AH06663: Unable to find code signature authority on module at /opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so that matches authority name "apache2" configured on LoadModule directive.
httpd: Syntax error on line 190 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Code signing error - not loading module at: /opt/homebrew/opt/php@5.6/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
```

How can fix them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `httpd` package from `Homebrew` instead of system Apache as that requires code signing.

- Unload the system Apache

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null
```

- Make sure `httpd` is installed using brew

```
brew install httpd
```

- Then you can configure httpd to run PHP using `/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` config file.
- Once done, restart `httpd` and it should work.

```
brew services restart httpd
```

Comment: thanks.. solved the above problem. but still wonder why occurred that error.

Comment: The error is because it is not able to find a code signing certificate name apache2, did you create one.
Here is the process to do so - https://blog.phusion.nl/2020/12/22/future_of_macos_apache_modules/

But I would still recommend using httpd from homebrew.